# How to fill in missing year range for each group in a table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe like:

```
species <- c("Tulip", "Tulip", "Tulip", "Dandy", "Dandy", "Dandy", "Rose", "Rose", "Rose")
Year <- c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2015, 2018, 2019, 2011, 2018, 2019)
length1 <- c(4, 2, 3, 4, 1,5,6,4,7)
length2 <- c(3,2,4, NA, 4, 4, NA, 3,2)

df <- data.frame(species, Year, length, length2)
```

The earliest year is 2011 for "Rose" in the species column, and the latest year is 2020 for "Tulip".

I want to add the missing years from 2011 to 2020 for all the groups in the "species" column, so that each group goes from 2011 to 2020.
And for column "length" and "length2", I want the values for the newly added years rows to be "0" since there is no data for it.

How would I do this?

edit: In my working data, I have up to 80 columns like "length1" and "length2"

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyr::complete` you could do:

```r
df |> 
  tidyr::complete(species, Year = 2011:2020, fill = list(length1 = 0, length2 = 0))
#> # A tibble: 30 × 4
#>    species  Year length1 length2
#>    <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 Dandy    2011       0       0
#>  2 Dandy    2012       0       0
#>  3 Dandy    2013       0       0
#>  4 Dandy    2014       0       0
#>  5 Dandy    2015       4       0
#>  6 Dandy    2016       0       0
#>  7 Dandy    2017       0       0
#>  8 Dandy    2018       1       4
#>  9 Dandy    2019       5       4
#> 10 Dandy    2020       0       0
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: thank you! In my working data, I have up to 80 columns like "length1" and "length2". Is there a way to use the script you provided without having to write each one after fill? TIA

Comment: Sure is this possible. You could e.g. do something like `to_fill <- names(df)[!names(df) %in% c("species", "Year")]; to_fill <- as.list(setNames(rep(0, length(to_fill)), to_fill))` to create the list with the columns to be filled with zeros. You could then do `complete(..., fill = to_fill)